# ¿Porqué no veo la lista de errores de validación en ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo en mi vista este código

```
@{
    if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "bg-red error-msg" });
    }
}
```

No me da ningún error, en el formulario entro datos con errores y sin embargo no se muestran, ahora si cambio este código por el siguiente si funciona, la pregunta es porqué debo usar @ en cada sentencia.

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "bg-red error-msg" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`@Html.ValidationSummary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationSummary%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%29) returna [`MvcHtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) que solo puede ser impreso en pantalla utilizando la expression `@`.
Cuando utilizas el bloque de codigo `@{ // codigo}` no estas imprimiendo, sino ejecutando un bloque de codigo. Por ejemplo en el bloque de codigo puedes obtener el resultado del metodo ValidationSummary e imprimirlo mas abajo:

```
@{
    MVCHtmlString resultado = null;
    if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        resultado = Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "bg-red error-msg" });
    }
}

@resultado
```

En resumen, `@expresion` solo se utiliza para imprimir mientras que el bloque de codigo `@{ }` se utiliza para realizar operaciones sobre el codigo a imprimir.